# How can I generate a signed ID token in the vault?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

So there's this [section](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/identity/tokens.html#generate-a-signed-id-token) on the vault's official site.

*Generate a Signed ID Token*

Use this endpoint to generate a signed ID (OIDC) token.
**Method**: `GET`   `identity/oidc/token/:name`

**Parameters**
`name (string: "")` – *The name of the role against which to generate a signed ID token*

**Sample request**:

```
    $ curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request GET \
    --data @payload.json \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/identity/oidc/token/role-001
```

**Sample response**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "client_id": "P6CfCzyHsQY4pMcA6kWAOCItA7",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjJkMGI4YjlkLWYwNGQtNzFlYy1iNjc0LWM3MzU4NDMyYmM1YiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJQNkNmQ3p5SHNRWTRwTWNBNmtXQU9DSXRBNyIsImV4cCI6MTU2MTQ4ODQxMiwiaWF0IjoxNTYxNDAyMDEyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tOjEyMzQiLCJzdWIiOiI2YzY1ZWFmNy1kNGY0LTEzMzMtMDJiYy0xYzc1MjE5YzMxMDIifQ.IcbWTmks7P5eVtwmIBl5rL1B88MI55a9JJuYVLIlwE9aP_ilXpX5fE38CDm5PixDDVJb8TI2Q_FO4GMMH0ymHDO25ZvA917WcyHCSBGaQlgcS-WUL2fYTqFjSh-pezszaYBgPuGvH7hJjlTZO6g0LPCyUWat3zcRIjIQdXZum-OyhWAelQlveEL8sOG_ldyZ8v7fy7GXDxfJOK1kpw5AX9DXJKylbwZTBS8tLb-7edq8uZ0lNQyWy9VPEW_EEIZvGWy0AHua-Loa2l59GRRP8mPxuMYxH_c88x1lsSw0vH9E3rU8AXLyF3n4d40PASXEjZ-7dnIf4w4hf2P4L0xs_g",
    "ttl": 86400
  }
}
```

How does `@payload.json` look like?